# how to plot analog filter impulse responce and frequency responce?

Tags: filters, filtering, analog-to-digital, chebyshev-filters

I an new to signal processing, working on a UWB radar data this data has a shape of frames for which every frame (list) has 164 values, I want to apply a bandpass filter with cutoff frequency of 1hz and 5hz to filter the noisy data. My filter is not giving the good results as I expected (the filtered data is the reason behind), so I was wondering how can I debug this:

```
Fs = 50
fp = np.array([1, 5])
Ap = 0.025
filter_order = 2
wc = (2 * pi * fp) / Fs

print('wc is ', wc)

sos = signal.cheby1(filter_order,
                    Ap,
                    wc,
                    'bandpass',
                    analog=True,
                    output='sos')

filt_data_UWB1 = signal.sosfilt(sos, data_UWB1_before)
```

How can I plot the impulse response, Frequency response and the data before and after being filtered (every sample of data is a frame that contains 164 point how i am supposed to plot this )?

Comment: sory that was a mistake bexause I changed the code I used sosfilt in that case

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish getting the impulse and frequency response for the filter given as a cascade of two second order filters  (sos) is to first combine the two filters by convolving the numerator and denominator coefficients:

$$H(s) = H_1(s) \circledast H_2(s)$$

The frequency response is then plotted by setting $s=j\omega$ and plotting the magnitude and phase vs $\omega$.

The impulse response is found from the inverse Laplace Transform of $H(s)$.

This can all be done directly in python:

To convolve the two filters use the `numpy.convolve` command.

To plot the frequency response use the `scipy.signal.freqs` command.

To plot the impulse response use the `scipy.signal.impulse` command.

This is demonstrated below, refer to the help documentation for the above commands for more details:

Frequency Response:

```
b = np.convolve(sos[0][:3], sos[1][:3])
a = np.convolve(sos[0][3:], sos[1][3:]) 
w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.semilogx(w, 20*np.log10(h))
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.semilogx(w, np.unwrap(np.angle(h)))
```

[image: Frequency Response]

Impulse Response:

```
t, y = signal.impulse((b,a), T=np.linspace(0, 150, 2**14))
plt.plot(t, y)
```

[image: Impulse Rsponse]